# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc12345'

Tags: python, regex, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am new to Python and Django. I don't even understand Regex properly. I have a project called `people` and an app called `individual`. 
I ran this in shell.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
[<User: abc12345>, <User: mno09876>, <User: xyz56789>]
```

I want:
When I visit `www.mysite.com/abc12345`, it should show `Hi abc12345` 
and when I visit `www.mysite.com/mno09876`, it should show `Hi mno09876`. This is my DetailView

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super[UserDetailView, self].get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

and This is my `/people/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from individual.models import *
from individual.views import UserDetailView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^fedidauth/', include('fedidauth.urls')),
    url(r'^individual/', include('fedidauth.urls')),
    url(r"^(?P<pk>\w+)/$", UserDetailView.as_view(), name="test.html"),
)
```

I have a template called base.html and test.html in /templates.

I get this error

`The current URL, abc12345, didn't match any of these.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using standart user, so User pk is always `int`, if you want to select user by username you have to rewrite `get_object` method of your view, like this:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
    username = self.kwargs.get('username', None)
    return queryset.get(username=username)
```

and add `username` to url:

```
url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/$", UserDetailView.as_view(), name="test.html"),
```

Comment: I have deleted my old UserDetailView class and now I get this error `UserDetailView is missing a queryset. Define UserDetailView.model, UserDetailView.queryset, or override UserDetailView.get_queryset().`

Comment: Add `model = User` to your view

Comment: I added, it gives this
`TemplateDoesNotExist auth/user_detail.html`

Comment: what is your template name for this view? add `template_name = 'your_template_name'` to view

Answer (score 0):

Even without knowing regex, it should be clear to you that you haven't got a URL matching "/abc12345/", you only have one matching "/user/12345". You've hard-coded that "user" prefix.

The other problem is that your regex only accepts digits (`\d+`) rather than alphanumeric characters (`\w+`).

Comment: I think there is a problem in DetailView. I have copied it from tutorials

Comment: Did you change the rest of the regex as I explained? What does it look like now?

Comment: One thing I want to mention that I have added this url line in myproject which is people/urls.py, not myapp/urls.py. I don't know whether to add in project/urls.py or myapp/urls.py

This is the url line now. `url(r"^/(?P<pk>\w+)/$", UserDetailView.as_view(), name="test.html"),
`

Comment: wait... I have deleted the first `/` from the URL and now the URL is `url(r"^(?P<pk>\w+)/$", UserDetailView.as_view(), name="test.html")` and the error is `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc12345'`